# AttributeError: 'BoxLayout' object has no attribute, textinput

Tags: python, android, kivy, kivy-language, kivymd

[Modified] I've got a problem when I press the button:I always get the error below. Can anyone suggest me how to solve this problem?

main.py file:

```
class MainApp(MDApp):



    def build(self):
        self.dati = Builder.load_file("conf.kv")
        return Builder.load_file("conf.kv")

    def show_data(self):
        print(self.boxlay.btn_nav.scr1.classe.text)

MainApp().run()
```

conf.kv file:

```
BoxLayout:
    orientation:'vertical'
    id: boxlay
    btn_nav:btn_nav

    MDToolbar:
        title: 'Bottom navigation'

    MDBottomNavigation:
        id: btn_nav
        scr1:scr1

        MDBottomNavigationItem:
            id: scr1
            classe:classe
            name: 'screen 1'
            text: 'Python'
            icon: 'language-python'

            MDTextField:
                id: classe
                hint_text: "Enter Class"
                pos_hint:{'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.5}
                size_hint_x:None
                width:300
            MDRectangleFlatButton:
                text: 'Python'
                pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.4}
                on_release: app.show_data()
```

running this code the error I receive is:

```
  on_release: app.show_data()
   File "main.py", line 27, in show_data
     print( AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'btn_nav')
 AttributeError: 'BoxLayout' object has no attribute 'classe'
```

Thanks for helping

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have `ids` defined, you can use them in your python code to access the widgets built from your `kv`. So the `show_data()` method can be:

```
def show_data(self):
    print(self.root.ids.classe.text)
```

Also, I notice that you are calling:

```
Builder.load_file("conf.kv")
```

twice in your `build()` method. While that is not an error, it is likely not what you want. The line:

```
self.dati = Builder.load_file("conf.kv")
```

Creates a complete copy of the GUI that is created by the line:

```
return Builder.load_file("conf.kv")
```

however, the widget tree referred to by `self.dati` is not the widget tree that is in your GUI, so `self.dati` is probably of no value. I suspect your `build()` method should be:

```
def build(self):
    self.dati = Builder.load_file("conf.kv")
    return self.dati
```

Comment: It worked perfectly! Thanks a lot for the explanation too